# Getting error while add new organizations in existing Consortium in hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am getting error while add new organizations in existing running network Consortium in hyperledger fabric. I have completed all the step mentioned on [this link](https://medium.com/thinkdecentralized/updating-the-consortium-definition-in-hyperledger-fabric-d1b6a9d079b0)
however when I reached to last step I am getting error as

```
Error: got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- error applying config update to existing channel 'syschannel': error authorizing update: error validating DeltaSet: policy for [Group]  /Channel/Consortiums not satisfied: implicit policy evaluation failed - 0 sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of the 'Admins' sub-policies to be satisfied
```

Please suggest how can solve it or give some hint.

HLF network specification

```
3 raft-orderer with CA
2 org with 2 peer each with CA
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that your orderer admin cert doesn't have a correct 'ou'.

First, you should check if the "Admins" cert has a correct 'ou'. try `openssl x509 -text -in crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/users/Admin@example.com/msp/signcerts/Admin@example.com-cert.pem` to get the details of the admins cert.

if you get the details like this:

```
    Issuer: C=US, ST=California, L=San Francisco, O=example.com, CN=ca.example.com
    Validity
        Not Before: Feb  9 08:53:00 2021 GMT
        Not After : Feb  7 08:53:00 2031 GMT
    Subject: C=US, ST=California, L=San Francisco, OU=client, CN=Admin@example.com
```

The OU witch should be admins but client here.

This problem happens in v1.4.3 and before and it was fixed in [this link](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/commit/cea596aad0b619398353b28551e2db4a4f43392a).

One solution to solve this problem is to delete the `EnableNodeOUs: true` in `crypto-config.yaml: OrdererOrgs`, and try all step again. Another solution is to use `cryptogen` v1.4.4 and above.