# Error to update orderermsp in Hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am try to migrate kafka to raft and try to update channel configuration in which EnableNodeOUs is true when I sign the update file with orderermsp it give error

result err: sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of the 'Admins' sub-policies to be satisfied

this are the command which i follow

```
# change work directories
mkdir maintenance_on_$CHANNEL_NAME && cd maintenance_on_$CHANNEL_NAME

# fetch current channel config
peer channel fetch config config_block.pb -o orderer0.dxb.com:7050 -c avanzachannel --tls --cafile $ORDERER_CA

# decode fetched channel config
configtxlator proto_decode --input config_block.pb --type common.Block --output config_block.json
jq .data.data[0].payload.data.config config_block.json > config.json

# save old config, to calculate delta in the future
cp config.json config_mod.json

cat config.json | grep name


# set maintenance mode in configs
sed -i 's/NORMAL/MAINTENANCE/g' config_mod.json

# encode old config to protopuf
configtxlator proto_encode --input config.json --type common.Config --output config.pb

# encode new config to protopuf
configtxlator proto_encode --input config_mod.json --type common.Config --output modified_config.pb

# compute delta between configs
configtxlator compute_update --channel_id $CHANNEL_NAME --original config.pb --updated modified_config.pb --output config_update.pb

# decode delta config
configtxlator proto_decode --input config_update.pb --type common.ConfigUpdate | jq . > config_update.json

# wrap delta config with a header
echo '{"payload":{"header":{"channel_header":{"channel_id":"avanzachannel", "type":2}},"data":{"config_update":'$(cat config_update.json)'}}}' | jq . > config_update_envelope.json

# encode wrapped config to protopuf
configtxlator proto_encode --input config_update_envelope.json --type common.Envelope --output config_update_in_envelope.pb

# sign channel update config


export CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/crypto/ordererOrganizations/dxb.com/orderers/orderer0.dxb.com/tls/ca.crt
export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/dxb.com/users/Admin@dxb.com/msp
export CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP


peer channel signconfigtx -f config_update_in_envelope.pb


# # export all needed env vars
# export CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="OrdererMSP"
# export CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/crypto/ordererOrganizations/dxb.com/orderers/orderer.dxb.com/tls/ca.crt
# export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/dxb.com/users/Admin@dxb.com/msp/
# export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.dxb.com:7051

# submit new channel config
peer channel update -f config_update_in_envelope.pb -c $CHANNEL_NAME -o orderer0.dxb.com:7050 --tls --cafile $ORDERER_CA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is the same as [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66052647/getting-error-while-add-new-organizations-in-existing-consortium-in-hyperledger/66116110#66116110).

The problem is that your orderer admin cert doesn't have a correct 'OU'.

You can follow the answer and try all steps again.

Comment: Thank you for you answer but the problem is this solution for when we are creation new network but in my case network is already running and have large amount of data.If i will create certificates again network will be destroy and all data will lost

Comment: I think it is not easy to solve the problem without creating a new network. Because the `genesis.block` was signed by the ordererMSP and has been saved in the blockfiles.